# Excel: How many hours of shift between two other times

Tags: excel, time, formula

Say I have a shift that is between 22:00-06:00, how can I calculate how many of those hours, are between 00:00-07:00 with a formula in cell E2?

| 1 | (A) Shift start | (B) Shift end | (C) Night time start | (D) Night time end | (E) Hours of night time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 22:00 | 06:00 | 00:00 | 07:00 | ?? |

Update: I realized that I will also need to check how many hours there are between two times that exists within the shift sometimes:

So if shift is from 07:00-22:00 I may need to check how many hours there are between say, 18:00-20:00..

Comment: You can check if the "Night" times fall in between the "Shift Start" and "Shift End" with `if` statements and then use the appropriate value in a formula and subtract. Post something you've tried and we will help.

Comment: Will (A) always be greater than (C)? If not it will make this much more complex.

Comment: @Kevin actually I realized that it won't. And sometimes I need to check how many hours there are between two times that exists within the shift. So if shift is from 07:00-22:00 I may need to check how many hours there are between say, 18:00-20:00. Have no example of what I tried, as I simply cannot compute the logic in my head to begin with.

Comment: Try this, I think it might work for you, or at least get you started  `=MOD(IF(D2>=B2, B2,D2)-C2,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Check if Shift End > Night Start. If yes then calculate the diff and cap it at Max of Night shift duration:

```
=IF(B2>=C2,MIN(ABS(C2-B2),ABS(D2-C2),ABS(A2-B2)),0)
```

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: Shouldn't you also check Night Start?

Comment: @Gangula.. I am so sorry, but I actually I realized that sometimes, I need to check how many hours there are between two times that exists within the shift. So if shift is from 07:00-22:00 I may need to check how many hours there are between say, 18:00-20:00. Any idea?

Comment: Based on what I understand, it works for this scenario too. Please try using the formula. I updated the screenshot accordingly